# simple iframe based AJAX script: first call yields 'null' element, subsequent call's work perfect. What am I not understanding here?

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe

Very simple AJAX script that does the following:

1. inserts hidden iframe for buffering server side output
2. iframe loads my PHP content silently into a div
3. PHP output is copied from server side div, to parent page div.

The problem is, the first call throws : 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null'.  All subsequent calls work perfectly. It's driving me nuts. I love the simplicity of this function but I'm obviously missing something.

**Javascript called from here:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- ajax -->
    <script src='ajax.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head> 
    <body>
        <a href='#' onClick="ajax_request('php.php','show_result');return false;">get ajax data</a>
        <div id='show_result'></div>
    <body>

</html>
```

**'ajax.js' file :**

```
function ajax_request(url,result_id)
{
    var ajax_iframe_id = 'ajax_iframe_loader';
    var ajax_iframe = document.getElementById(ajax_iframe_id);

    // create hidden iframe transfer buffer if it's not created already.
    if (ajax_iframe == null)
    {

        var element = document.createElement("iframe");
        element.setAttribute('src',url);
        element.setAttribute('id',ajax_iframe_id);
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        element.style.display='none';
        element.style.width='1';
        element.style.height='1';
        element.style.border='0';

        ajax_iframe = element;
    }

    // load server side page into iframe buffer
    ajax_iframe.src = url;

    // get the outputted result from inside our transfer div
    var iframe_inner_doc = ajax_iframe.contentDocument || ajax_iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var content_to_transfer = iframe_inner_doc.getElementById('to_transfer').innerHTML;

    // paste result
    document.getElementById(result_id).innerHTML = content_to_transfer;

}
```

**'php.php' server script that outputs the result for transfer via AJAX (random number)**

```
<html>
<body>
<div id='to_transfer'><?=mt_rand(5, 15);?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please a snippet where is your ajax_request function called

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this inside your if statement

```
ajax_iframe = element;
```

Comment: added it, but Now It's throwing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null" @ content_to_transfer line.  So it still doesn't exist for some reason..? Thanks though.

Comment: What is the value of result_id?

Comment: That's the weird thing.  It throws an error, I can't get a value at all.  Doesn't exist.  On all subsequent execution's the value is my desired output from my PHP page.